# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to send messages from one point to an other, it was working for a while, then when I went back home, it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
line 20, in connect
    self.mySocket.connect((self.serverName, self.serverPort))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The code for these  are below. I even tried running it on a Mac and I got similar errors.

**Client**

```
import socket

    serverName = "my_IP_Address"
    serverPort = 12000

    class User:
        mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        def __init__(self):
            self.serverName = serverName
            self.serverPort = serverPort

        def connect(self):
            print("Trying to connect at " + str(self.serverName) + " on port " + str(self.serverPort))
            self.mySocket.connect((self.serverName, self.serverPort))

        def sendMessage(self, msg):
            newS = msg.encode('utf-8')
            self.mySocket.send(newS)
            modifiedData = self.mySocket.recv(2048)

        def closeSocket(self):
            self.mySocket.close()

        def listen(self):
            self.mySocket.bind(('', self.serverPort))
            self.mySocket.listen(1)
            print("We are ready to receive data on port " + str(serverPort))
            while (1):
                print("** attempting ** ")
                connectionSocket, addr = self.mySocket.accept()
                rcvMsg = connectionSocket.recv(2048)
                newMsg = "I have received: " + rcvMsg.decode('utf-8')
                print(newMsg)
                newMsg = newMsg.encode('utf-8')
                connectionSocket.send(newMsg)
                connectionSocket.close()

                if (rcvMsg.decode('utf-8') == 'done'):
                    break
            print("done listening")

    def main():
        userA = User()
        userA.listen()

    main()
```

**Server**

```
def main():
    userA = User()
    userA.connect()
    msg = "Hello from the lab"
    while(msg != "done"):
        userA.sendMessage(msg)
        msg = input("please type another message to send: ")
    print("done transmitting messages")


main()
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows.. yeah.......

Comment: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` it sounds to me like the packets are refused.. Firewall maybe.

Comment: I fixed the firewall issue and changed the IP address and it worked for one message, but when the user is prompted to give another, everything gets hung up (not a crash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending too many requests and my ISP I was on blocked the request (hence it refused the connection). Once I moved to a new network, I was able to get it to work again.